# is an electron BrowserWindow id guaranteed to be unique for the life of an application?

Tags: electron

If my electron app opens and closes lots of `BrowserWindow`s, is each one guaranteed to have a unique id?

So, within a single run of my app, if I open a `BrowserWindow` and close it, then open a new `BrowserWindow`:  is there any chance the new `BrowserWindow` will have the same id as the one that I closed?

Comment: You can't expect it'd be unique. It is guaranteed to be unique among all current instances only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expect unique ID for every instance based on the current source (1.8.4 release or 2.0.0-beta.5)

On the native side `BrowserWindow` implementation inherits from `TrackableObject` which actually handles IDs. `win.id` API looks like [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v2.0.0-beta.5/atom/browser/api/atom_api_window.cc#L983)

```cpp
int32_t Window::ID() const {
  return weak_map_id();
}
```

ID returned by `weak_map_id()` is constructed in `TrackableObject` like [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/b429dafa381bb9685e347f5547a03861ab4f2b19/atom/browser/api/trackable_object.h#L121)

```cpp
weak_map_id_ = ++next_id_;
weak_map_->Set(isolate, weak_map_id_, wrapper);
```

where `next_id_` is a static member across trackable instances and is never decreased.

Thus, browser IDs should always keep incrementing during the whole run of your app regardless of deletions.

---

The following silly example confirms the behavior

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
let win = null
app.once('ready', () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    win = new BrowserWindow()
    console.log(win.id)
  }, 1000)
  setInterval(() => {
    win.destroy()
  }, 2100)
})
```

Comment: Although for now you should be aware of [this bug](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12036)